# A better BASH? - BASH and "maddening" syntax

Tags: linux, bash, syntax

**A Better BASH?**

I am pretty inexperienced with BASH, but recently I have been using it to execute my program code for batch processing of data for various experiments in the lab.

I have been using C/C++ for quite a few years now, so I would consider myself "reasonably competent" programmer.

... Not so when it comes to bash...

I realize that BASH (or at least SH or its predecessor) has been around since something probably like 1971, and is therefore very old and hence perhaps there are 10^6 + 1 reasons why the syntax is the way it is (backwards compatibility being one of them), HOWEVER, today I attempted to do this:

```
for DEPTH in {$START..$END}
do
    ...
done
```

Which doesn't work, because `{$START..$END}` evaluates to `{9..9}` (the string, not the expansion `'9'`) in this case...

In order to fix this I had to do the following:

```
for DEPTH in $(eval echo "{$START..$END}")
do
    ...
done
```

Which is... erm... bizarre. More so than Matlab's occasionally hairy syntax. (I don't think that's too controversial a statement, my assumption being that anyone who uses a syntactically coherent language like Fortran, C or Python (or any others) is likely to agree that this really isn't very nice. Apart from anything else it's far too much to type (IMO) to accomplish such a simple task.

I am aware that BASH now supports a C-like syntax:

```
for (( c=$START; c<=$END; c++ ))
```

But that's really not a lot better... Mainly because we have some strange and mysterious double parentheses and now we are using things like `<=` and `++` which can't be used anywhere else (in a BASH script) as far as I know.

There are also other things which bit me like `==` for string comparison, BUT `-eq` for numeric comparison. (Again, related to above comment.) What's going on here?

So my question is, is there a "better BASH" which is syntactically more "polished"? Why does BASH insist on this mad method of doing things? What are those 10^ + 1 reasons?

I know about tcsh/csh, but I don't consider `foreach n ( 1 2 3 4 5 )` to be much improvement, so I've been using BASH because at least it's widely used so I can get help easily when I run into these "syntactic potholes".

Comment: The `{a..b}` problem comes from Bash trying to include features from `csh`.  :(

Comment: If you find bash syntax awkward (and I'm not necessarily disagreeing with you), I think you'll find csh/tcsh to be much worse. It makes some simple things simple, but overall its syntax is far less coherent. Obligatory link: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Comment: The proponents of [tag:zsh] would suggest that it is better.  You might well find the same for many other shells -- they tend to be written because people don't like the default shell, which is typically based on POSIX shell, which in turn is based on Bourne shell.

Comment: BTW, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls covers the specific item you asked about here. Being familiar with it is worthwhile.

Comment: One of the reasons zsh people prefer zsh and the reason at least some bash people (including myself) prefer bash are one and the same: zsh breaks backwards compatibility when the older behavior is stupid. I'm in the camp that thinks that there are times when doing stupid things for compatibility is worthwhile, but it's certainly not cut-and-dried.

Comment: As an aside -- string comparison should be `=`, not `==`, if you want to be in habits that are compatible with POSIX; `==` is a bash extension.

Comment: Bash and C/C++ use different paradigms, so this is a bit like asking why Haskell/Prolog maddeningly doesn't let you increment variables. Bash's evaluation model is really more like a recursive, single pass macro processor.

Answer (score 3):

First, the "weird double parentheses" are how you tell bash that you want to do arithmetic.  They're a synonym for `let` that let you avoid having to quote everything.  If you don't use `((`..`))` or `let`, everything is just strings.

But you can use `((`...`))` elsewhere, not just for `for` loops.  You can include the result of an arithmetic expression with `$((`...`))`, or just do math to set variables without any output using `((`...`))` (e.g. `(( x = y/2 + 3 ))` or do comparisons (e.g. `if (( y%2 == 0 ))`), and on and on.

Note that in arithmetic contexts you don't have to put dollar signs on the variables - they will automatically be replaced with their numeric values.

The curly-brace expansions via `{`...`}` are a hacked-on affair that is not well-integrated with the core POSIX semantics, much like the history substitutions with `!`.  In particular, brace expansion happens before any other substitution.  So given`{$foo..$bar}`, the curly-brace expander sees `$foo` and `$bar` as literal strings, not numbers, so they don't trigger the range expansion.  By the time bash expands `$foo` to its value, it's too late for the curly braces to do anything.

There are lots of other languages which you would probably consider superior to bash that work well for command-line scripting; this is the whole reason Perl was invented.  Now you have it and Python and Ruby at your fingertips on most systems that have bash. The main advantage bash still has is that the "API" is the same as the "UI"... you don't have to translate from shell commands to library or API calls. But if you're doing anything terribly complex, you're probably better off switching languages.